# Как записать return функции в файл?

Tags: python

```
drivers = get_drivers(desc=False)
```

```
[Driver(num='1', driver_id='SVF', name='Sebastian Vettel', team='FERRARI', lap_time='0:01:04.415000'),
 Driver(num='2', driver_id='VBM', name='Valtteri Bottas', team='MERCEDES', lap_time='0:01:12.434000')]
```

записать нужно полностью, списком namedtuple

Comment: Так каким образом вы хотите это записать? (Иначе вы просто не можете записать получившийся список в файл?)

Comment: Ну попробуйте просто записать в файл `str(drivers)`

Comment: @CrazyElf действительно просто, а я уже циклами такое нагородил), спасибо

Comment: Можно ещё попробовать repr(drivers), может разницы не будет, а может и будет, тогда выберите, какой вариант лучше )

Comment: разницы не оказалось )